# knitr: how to set keep.blank.lines=T (for whole document) with tidy=F

Tags: r, formatting, knitr

For my whole document, I would like to set

```
keep.blank.lines=T
```

How can I do this? Note that I also want the option

```
tidy=F
```

for the whole document, too.

Answer (score 1):

`tidy=FALSE` in `knitr` chunk options implies `keep.blank.line=TRUE` for `formatR`, so you only need

```
opts_chunk$set(tidy=FALSE)
```

in the beginning of your document.

Comment: I have that set, but the blank lines are gone.

Comment: Using knitr v. 1.4.1 and formatR 0.9.  It started happening with a recent update (to 1.4.1, which uses highr ?).  I noticed the new syntax highlighting as well as no more blank lines in the output.

Comment: That is a bug of the highr package, which has been fixed in the development version: `install.packages('highr', repos = 'http://rforge.net', type = 'source')`